# Dimension attribute listing order

Tags: excel, ssas

I am setting my SSAS dimension attributes as Properties for Excel. Is there a way to order the listing of attributes in a SSAS dimension so that the Excel will show the attributes in a specific listed order?

Note: I am not talking about OrderBy Property of the attribute to Order the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way. They are listed in tooltips alphabetically.